# Cannot submit data with XMLHTTPRequest with progress bar in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to submit data with ajax XMLHTTPRequest and there must be progress bar so that to show the status of file upload. I have worked out to some level where progress bar is running but the file does not get uploaded Here is my code. Please help to solve my issue.

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('posting_comment_'+a)[0]);
        alert(fd);
        fd.append("file_m_id",a);
        var bar = $('.bar');
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();        
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);


        xhr.open("POST", "<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/do_upload_video",true);
        xhr.send(fd);  




        function uploadProgress(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
            document.getElementById('progressNumber_'+a).innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
            $("#status_"+a).animate( { width: percentComplete.toString()+"%"}, 5);
            }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's anything to send, for instance `getElementById('id')[0]` ***always*** results in `undefined`

Comment: @user3653474, what is the error?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest- there is no error.

Comment: @adeno : Yes i'm sure, in alert(fd); prints object [formData]. but no data gets uploaded

Comment: Please help me to solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('posting_comment_'+a)[0]);
alert(fd);
fd.append("file_m_id",a);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){ 
    var percent; 
    if(event.lengthComputable===true){ 
          percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
          uploadProgress(percent); 
    } 
});

xmlhttp.open("post", "<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/do_upload_video");
xmlhttp.send(fd);

function uploadProgress(percent) {
    document.getElementById('progressNumber_'+a).innerHTML = percent?percent+'%':0;
    $("#status_"+a).animate( { width: percent?percent+'%':0}, 5);
}
```

[Check my blog here to upload files using ajax with progress bar](http://ijasnahamed.blogspot.in/2016/01/multiple-file-upload-using-ajax-with.html)

Comment: Thanks Ijas! I tried it but the image is not uploading but the progress bar is working. Can u please see to it.

Comment: This is my blog about file upload using ajax with progress bar. check here. http://ijasnahamed.blogspot.in/2016/01/multiple-file-upload-using-ajax-with.html